# Why first two digits are lost after using left-shift bitwise operator?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, strtoull

I am storing a hexadecimal value in a uint64_t variable. When I call `strtoull()` to convert the string to a hexadecimal value I get the correct result, but when I do a left-shift (`<<`) by 32 I am losing the first two digits.

The string I am testing is `"398a59b412"`. I expect to get back `398a59b41200000000` but instead of this I get `8a59b41200000000`.

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/modes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define u8 unsigned char
#define INT_BITS 32 

unsigned long long int ecountGeneration()
{
   char *test_count = "398a59b412";
   unsigned long long x = 0x398a59b412 | 0x00;
   const char *test_bearer = "15";
    const char *test_direction = "1";
    unsigned long long result;
    int64_t result_count = 0;
     
     

  //errno = 0;
   result_count = strtoull(test_count, '\0', 16);
  uint64_t  result_bearer = strtoull(test_bearer, NULL, 16);
  uint64_t  result_direction = strtoull(test_direction, NULL, 16);
  result_count = result_count  | 0x0;
  uint64_t x1 = result_count<<32;
  printf("-->%" PRIx64 "\n" ,x1);
  uint64_t x2 = result_bearer<<27;
  uint64_t x3 = result_direction<<26;
  uint64_t x4 = x1 | x2 | x3;
  
  printf("----->%" PRIu64 "\n" , x1);


  return result;
}
```

Comment: How many bits do you think that 0x398a59b412 occupies?

Comment: That is not two bits; it is two hexadecimal digits, which is eight bits.

Comment: very interesting : `0x398a59b412 | 0x00`. What do you think it does ?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Two digits.

Comment: Also, `strtoull` returns an unsigned type, but you assign the result to an `int64_t`.

Comment: Hi Bob, isn't uint64_t for unsigned variable?

Comment: Yes, but in the posted snippet `result_count` is an `int64_t`, not an `uint64_t`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Oh yes. That was a mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `result_count<<32` causes undefined behaviour (integer overflow by left shifting signed value)

Answer (score 1):

Because 0x398a59b412 is **40 bits** in size!

In hexadecimal, each digit can have a range of `0` thru `15`, which requires 4 bits (aka a 'nibble'). `0x398a59b412` has 10 digits, so it is 40 bits size.  Further, the `<<` operator in C is not a 'cyclic shift', so the leftmost two nibbles are truncated (lost).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could I work around that in some way?

Comment: @P__J__ of course 4. think int type has 32 bit (in x86) even though possess value under its bound. very likely.

Comment: Hey. I am not using that in my code. I am sorry I did not omit that. I was just playing around.

Comment: @Juhi if you're using gcc, how about using __int128? even though it's non-standard, it's implemented on gcc.

Comment: @Adrian Mole Thanks for help! should I edit answer? - Sorry, I'm new

Comment: The shift causes undefined behaviour. Appearance of digit truncation is just one possible outcome